# Async call never fired

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to make an asynchronous call to load data from a RESTful WCF service via an HttpClient. The code is in a Portable Class Library (PCL) that is used from Xamarin UI. It appears that the async call is never fired. I have read blogs about problems in this area and I believe I have addressed them.

I make the call from a client side data repository class as below:

```
    public MyRepository()
    {
        Task.Run(async () => { await LoadDataAsync(url); });
    }
    public async Task LoadDataAsync(string uri)
    {
        if (allRecords != null) **// Breakpoint here never hit.**
        {
            string responseJsonString = null;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    Task<HttpResponseMessage> getResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await getResponse;
                    responseJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyListItem>>(responseJsonString);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should really not do a empty `catch (Exception ex)`, you are just hiding errors that will be hard to diagnose bugs.

Comment: Can you repro this on desktop .NET?

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would avoid calling async methods inside constructors..

and do something like this

(Create a static method that returns an instance of your class)

```
    const string uri = "https://www.webservice.com/api/getdata";
    private List<MyListItem> myList;

    public static async Task<MyRepository> GetMyRepository()
    {
        MyRepository myRepository = new MyRepository();
        await myRepository.LoadDataAsync(uri);

        return myRepository; 
    }

    public MyRepository()
    {
    }

    public async Task LoadDataAsync(string uri)
    {
        if (allRecords != null) **// Breakpoint here never hit.**
        {
            string responseJsonString = null;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    Task<HttpResponseMessage> getResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await getResponse;
                    responseJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyListItem>>(responseJsonString);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't explain why you're encountering that issue but perhaps this might help you.

Comment: This is a good solution, however one change I would do is now that you have a static factory method make the constructor private so only the factory method can new up instances.

Comment: Yeah, it should be converted to a singleton class that is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're invoking a "fire-and-forget" asynchronous call from within your constructor. This should be avoided and is the reason that it appears that your code isn't being called - when it probably is...I suggest making the following changes:

```
public async Task LoadDataAsync(string uri)
{
    if (allRecords != null) **// Breakpoint here never hit.**
    {
        string responseJsonString = null;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                Task<HttpResponseMessage> getResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await getResponse;
                responseJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyListItem>>(responseJsonString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how there is actually no change, except for the removal of the constructor all together. When this object is instantiated - simply await the invocation of the `LoadDataAsync` function.

```
public async Task SomeConsumerOfYourObject()
{
    var wcfObj = new YourWcfObject();
    await wcfObj.LoadDataAsync(this.Uri);

    // Then you're good...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why it is not firing: Probably because your application is exiting before the thread that you intended to start via Task.Run could actually start.

In order to test the above theory, put a Thread.Sleep right after you call (this is not the solution, but a test):

```
public MyRepository()
{
    Task.Run(async () => { await LoadDataAsync(url); });
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); //will sleep for 10 seconds
}
```

Anyways, to take advantage of the async method you should remove the Task.Run altogether, call await on the function directly, the thread will yield after await gets run on the "getresponse" object allowing to do other things till you actually need to wait for it, when you actually need to wait for it, call await then.